# Filtering an array with an array in AngularJS

Tags: arrays, angularjs, filter, ionic-framework

I tried filtering a group of checkboxes with an array like so:

`<ion-checkbox ng-repeat="user in users | filter: {id: group.members}" ng-model="user.checked">{{user.info.name}}</ion-checkbox>`

where `group.members` is an array of `user.id` and it just doesn't show anything.

users Array:

`[12345,123456]`

group.members Array:

`[12345]`

I'm trying to accomplish **not showing** the `group.members` in the list of `users`, because in this case a user is trying to invite another `user` to the `group` and why invite someone who's already a member?

I tried creating my own filter, but its just a mess:

```
.filter('existingMembers', function() {
    return function(users, members) {
        return users.filter(function(user) {

            for (var i in user.id) {

                if (members.indexOf(user.id[i]) != -1) {
                    return;
                }
            }
            return user;

        });
    };
})
```

Comment: @NikhileshKV everything shows correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some messing around, this is the solution. [See the plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/IVwj6kuWZoJmwB5V29UL) for a working example.
I think this should do the trick:

Template:

```
<ion-checkbox ng-repeat="user in users | filter: excludeMembers:group.members" ng-model="user.checked">{{user.info.name}}</ion-checkbox>
```

Angular filter:

```
app.filter('excludeMembers', function(){
  return function(users, members){
    return users.filter(function(user){
      return members.indexOf(user.id) === -1;
    });
  }
})
```

**Long explanation**

The filter takes the array you are filtering against as a first parameter as a default, then with the colon notation (:) you can supply optional arguments, in your case: the group. The filter should return a function, which will be run. The return value should be a filtered array. We also use a native javascript filter function (confusing, whoa) to check against the group array.

Comment: @rcpilotp51 Updated.

Comment: @rcpilot51 Updated (bis)

Comment: @JustusRomijn Now it is working, but in the opposite fashion i would like it to. How would I modify the filter to **not return the group members**?

Comment: `return members.indexOf(user.id) === -1;` ??

Comment: @JustusRomijn `=== -1;` did it. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @rcpilotp51 Yeah, in that case I would give the filter a different name :). excludeMembers for example.

Answer (score 0):

By utilizing a look up table (LUT) object you may do some filtering like this with pure JS.

```js
var gmems = [12345, 567890],
    users = [12345,123456,432567,1234987,567890],
      lut = gmems.reduce((p,c) => {p[c]=true; return p},{}),
      res = users.filter(e => !lut[e]);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(res, 0, 2) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: thanks but I would like to use a filter. any other suggestions? thank you

Comment: Do you mean a filtering function? Then you may utilize the above code as `function userFilter(u, g) { var lut = g.reduce((p,c) => {p[c]=true; return p},{}); return u.filter(e => !lut[e])};`